# Insert csv data into database with single quote in data

Tags: php, csv, insert

```
if (($handle = fopen($source_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $columns = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",");
    foreach ($columns as &$column) {
        $column = str_replace(".","",$column);
    }
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        while(count($data) < count($columns)) {
            array_push($data, NULL);
        }
        $c = count($data);
        for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
            $data[$i] = "'{$data[$i]}'";
        }

        $sql[] = '(' . implode(',', $data) . ", '" . $_POST['custgroup'] . "'," . $_POST['user_id'] . ')';
    }

 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;","root",""); 

 $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $target_table (". implode(',', $columns) .',custgroup,user_id) VALUES ' .implode(',', $sql));
 $insert->execute();
```

I have a script like this which will insert csv data into database according to header,and 2 extra datas which is group and user id. It works well , but when my name in csv file is 
`Sher's Aria` then it will have error.I know it's because of the symbol single quote in the name, `'` , so what can I do to solve this problem so that any name with single quote can be inserted as well?

Thank you.

Edit:

```
function csv_file_to_mysql_table($source_file, $target_table, $max_line_length=10000) {

if($source_file != '')
  {

    if (($handle = fopen($source_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
     $columns = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",");
     $esc_columns = array();
         foreach ($columns as &$column) {
            $column = str_replace(".","",$column);
            $esc_columns[] = escapeSqlName($column);
          }

      $esc_columns[] = escapeSqlName('custgroup');
      $esc_columns[] = escapeSqlName('user_id');

      $sqlsmttempl = 'INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)';
      $sqlsmt = sprintf($sqlstmttempl,
      escapeSqlName($target_table), 
      implode(',', $esc_columns), 
      implode(',',array_fill(0, count($esc_columns), '?')) // the parameter placeholders
 );

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;","root",""); 

$insert = $db->prepare($sqlsmt);  

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    while(count($data) < count($columns)) {
        $data[] = NULL;
    }
    $data[] = $_POST['custgroup'];
    $data[] = $_POST['user_id'];


 if($insert->execute($data))
 {
   header("Location:customer-search.php");
 }
else
{
echo "no";
 }

}

 fclose($handle);
   }
 }


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$file = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
$table = 'UserAddedRecord';

csv_file_to_mysql_table($file,$table);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using PDO, so you should make PDO handle your escaping for you
with your prepared statement. The code below does that.

Note that you still have a possible security issue because you assign table
and column names dynamically. The code below attempts to make sure that won't
result in any SQL injections, but you should still be cautious.

But you won't have any problems with unescaped input to the `VALUES()` part,
and the insertions should be much faster since you prepare the statement
only once.

```
function escapeSqlName($name, $quotechar='`') {
        // This is to escape column names. This $quotechar ONLY WORKS WITH MYSQL
        // ANSI syntax is to use $quotechar='"' and double them where-ever " is in the table name.
        return $quotechar.str_replace($quotechar, $quotechar.$quotechar, $name).$quotechar;
}

if (($handle = fopen($source_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $columns = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",");
    $esc_columns = array();
    foreach ($columns as &$column) {
        $column = str_replace(".","",$column);
        $esc_columns[] = escapeSqlName($column);
    }
    // your two extra columns
    $esc_columns[] = escapeSqlName('custgroup');
    $esc_columns[] = escapeSqlName('user_id');

    $sqlsmttempl = 'INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)';
    $sqlsmt = sprintf($sqlsmttempl,
        escapeSqlName($target_table), // the escaped table name
        implode(',', $esc_columns), // the escaped column names
        implode(',',array_fill(0, count($esc_columns), '?')) // the parameter placeholders
    );
    // $sqlsmt should now look like 'INSERT INTO `thetable` (`col1`,`col2`,...) VALUES (?,?,...)';

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;","root",""); 

    $insert = $db->prepare($sqlsmt);  // prepare statement ONCE, execute with new values MULTIPLE TIMES

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        while(count($data) < count($columns)) {
            $data[] = NULL;
        }
        // your two extra values
        $data[] = $_POST['custgroup'];
        $data[] = $_POST['user_id'];

        $insert->execute($data); // does data escaping for you.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your script Francis and I'm so sorry for my late response . I tried it just now , but I'm getting this error? `Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings`

Comment: You should give line that has the error, but I think it's this one: `$esc_columns = escapeSqlName($column);` should be `$esc_columns[]`. Fixed in answer

Comment: I'm sorry and yes , that's the line.I changed it and it runs without error,but data is not inserted.I tried to edit it but seems too difficult to me...can help me to take a look?I post it in the question.Thank you.

Comment: The code you posted has a syntax error. There's a missing close-curly brace.

Comment: Oh because I didn't paste the `else` part coding in the question so I think I miss the curly brace.So sorry..but in my script all curly brace is there.

Comment: There were typos in two variable names: `str_replace($quotechar, $quotechar.$quotechar, $column)` and `$sqlsmt = sprintf($sqlstmttempl,`. Replace with revised answer. I've gone so far as to set up a db table and csv file to test this, so it's definitely working. Add `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` option to your db connection to debug further problems.

Comment: It works now.Thank you so much Francis...honestly I not really understand the coding but I will definitely learn it.And so sorry to disturb you..Thanks for your patient and all the solutions,thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

One benefit (or maybe even purpose) of prepared statments is the separation of the actual statement and its parameters (the paylod data).
Instead of building a string that contains the paylod data you should bind those parameters via [PDOStatement::bindParam](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [PDOStatement::bindValue](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).

Answer (score -1):

### CSV escaping

Surround your fields with quotes to contain the apostrophes in a CSV file. For example in your CSV:

```
"title", "name"
"Mr", "O'Hara"
```

### Database escaping

You should look at escaping your data using PDO as @VolkerK suggests.

Comment: Considering that the real problem here is improper escaping of input to an sql query, giving a workaround that appears to solve the problem but doesn't is very dangerous.

Comment: @FrancisAvila I was writing the DB escaping example, but noticed that VolkerK had already covered it. To be clear I was no providing a work around, but pointing out CSV data should be laid out. To suggest that it is dangerous to correctly format a CSV file is laughable.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with his CSV file (`fgetcsv` reads it fine), He's not building a CSV file, and this is not a sufficient set of escaping rules to build a CSV properly. (Not that he should do it by hand anyway--he should use `fputcsv`.) But since you've altered your question so that it is merely unhelpful instead of harmful, I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score -1):

Use

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

for each entry in the csv file before inserting the value in the array.

so, replace

```
$data[$i] = "'{$data[$i]}'";
```

with

```
$data[$i] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($data[$i])."'";
```